# Detect if a string is a function in php?

Tags: php

I know that in php you can use variable functions like:

```
function some_func(){}
$name = "some_func";
$$name();
```

But, what I really want to know is if you can check if a function exists without executing it. That is not via:

```
if($name()){}
```

Comment: Check the manual: `function_exists()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **`function_exists()`**. It will do exactly what you are asking for.

Here's how (from the **PHP manual**):

> *bool* **function_exists**( *string* **$name**)

It will check the list of defined functions (both built-in and user-defined) for **`$name`**

**NOTE:**
If you wish to check if a member function (method) exists use `method_exists`.

Find out more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)